# Anemic class that binds functionality

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have cleanly separated functionality of a message bus - namely the diagnostics (optional), sending, decoding and the bus driver, I need to now bind this together and have done so with a `MessageBus` class.

It feels anemic though, with a lot of pass through methods.

On the flip side it is necessary for coordinating `StartAsync()` which links dependencies on the `driver` and `receiver` (binding them so they can call back) - I saw no other way of achieving this if I registered all individual interfaces via an inversion of control container as it would get out of sync (how to bind the driver to the decoder for instance).

If this is the wrong place for comments on code please let me know and I will remove straight away. Any pointers much appreciated.

```
public class MessageBus : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MessageBusReceiver receiver;
    private readonly MessageBusPublisher publisher;
    private readonly IMessageBusDriver driver;
    private int isRunning;
    private readonly MessageBusDiagnostics diagnostics = null;

    public MessageBus(IMessageBusDriver driver, SerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, ITypeIdentifier typeIdentifier, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, bool isDebug = false)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.publisher = new MessageBusPublisher(serializerRegistry, driver, typeIdentifier);
        this.receiver = new MessageBusReceiver(serializerRegistry, typeIdentifier, loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MessageBusReceiver>());
        if (isDebug)
            diagnostics = new MessageBusDiagnostics(driver, loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MessageBusDiagnostics>());
    }

    void AssertIsRunning()
    {
        if (this.isRunning == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(StartAsync)} must be called before calling other methods.");
    }

    public async Task SubscribeAsync(string topic, QualityOfService qos, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AssertIsRunning();
        await this.driver.SubscribeAsync(topic, qos, null, null, null, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task UnsubscribeAsync(string topic, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AssertIsRunning();
        await this.driver.UnsubscribeAsync(topic, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(Func<object, Task> receiveApplicationMessage)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.isRunning, 1, 0) == 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already running.");

        this.receiver.OnMessageDecoded = receiveApplicationMessage;
        await this.driver.StartAsync(this.receiver.ReceiveMessageFromMessageBusDriver);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.isRunning, 0, 1) == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not running.");

        await this.driver.StopAsync();
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync(object notification, string busPath, QualityOfService qos = QualityOfService.AtMostOnce, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AssertIsRunning();
        await this.publisher.PublishAsync(notification, busPath, qos, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync(object notification, Dictionary<string, string[]> pathTokens = null, QualityOfService qos = QualityOfService.AtMostOnce, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AssertIsRunning();
        await this.publisher.PublishAsync(notification, pathTokens, qos, cancellationToken);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.driver.Dispose();
        this.diagnostics?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: A fast tip: you can optimize out all `async` State Machines here as you have only one `await` and no code after it and it's not inside `using` or `try-catch` statement. For example `public Task UnsubscribeAsync(...) { AssertIsRunning(); return this.driver.UnsubscribeAsync(...); }`

Comment: @aepot thank you, indeed you are right just a couple of pointers - been burnt in the past with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63584024/simple-injector-instance-is-requested-outside-the-context-of-an-active-async-s and also `ConfigureAwait` I believe would be best practice (in some cases) https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't affect the above tip.

Comment: David Fowler (ASP.NET Architect) [suggests](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-asyncawait-over-directly-returning-task) to prefer `await` over `return Task`. Please read the all reasoning and then decide which approach you choose.

Comment: Why do you have a single class which can handle everything? Why don't you introduce separate interfaces for publisher and consumer clients?

Comment: Peter thats what i wanted, however i need to chain the interfaces in `public async Task StartAsync(Func<object, Task> receiveApplicationMessage)` this is causing me to bind it all together (and pass through method calls - my exact dislike)

Comment: It would be possible to separate interfaces, but i need away to start (publisher cannot be used until receiver is started).

Comment: @morleyc Why can't you start publisher without consumer?

Comment: I have realized my specific use of MQTT.net lib is driving the upstream pattern (other libs, such as NetMQ and Azure Service Bus do not have to be "started" and if it is doing background work then it is likely initialized/started in the constructor and stopped in dispose), I will have a go at changing this and using a fluent configuration to "build" the message bus which will do the binding for me. This will then allow proper and neat separation of concerns. I will post up as an answer once done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what i was missing was a "builder" class that could take care of the construction, and allow the interfaces to be returned.

Not all transport types needed to be "started", so i left that concern to the builder of the specific bus (i.e. MQTT transport would have different requirements to Kafka for instance).

Any "stopping" can be done on dispose - any one not wanting to receive messages before then can unsubscribe via the `ISubscriber` interface.

So we build the base `MessageBusBuilderBase` class:

```
public abstract class MessageBusBuilderBase
{
    private MessageBusDiagnostics messageBusDiagnostics;
    public bool IsDebugEnabled => messageBusDiagnostics != null;

    protected abstract Task<ITransport> NewTransportAsync(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, Func<TransportMessage, Task> receiveMessage);

    public async Task<BuiltInterfaces> CreateAsync(IMessageSerializer[] serializers, ITypeIdentifier typeIdentifier, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, bool isDebug = false)
    {
        var serializerRegistry = new SerializerRegistry(serializers);
        var receiver = new MessageDeserializer(serializerRegistry, typeIdentifier, loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MessageDeserializer>());
        var transport = await NewTransportAsync(loggerFactory, receiver.ReceiveMessageFromTransport);
        var publisher = new MessagePublisher(serializerRegistry, transport, typeIdentifier);
        var subscriber = new MessageSubscriber(transport);

        // chain up event handler functions
        receiver.OnMessageDecoded = subscriber.ReceiveMessageFromDeserializer;

        if (isDebug)
            this.messageBusDiagnostics = new MessageBusDiagnostics(transport, loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MessageBusDiagnostics>());

        return new BuiltInterfaces(publisher, subscriber);
    }
}
```

And the specific derived class for `MqttMessageBusBuilder`:

```
public class MqttMessageBusBuilder : MessageBusBuilderBase
{
    private readonly MqttSettings settings;
    public MqttMessageBusBuilder(MqttSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    protected override async Task<ITransport> NewTransportAsync(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, Func<TransportMessage, Task> receiveMessage)
    {
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MqttMessageBusBuilder>();
        logger.LogDebug($"{nameof(MqttMessageBusBuilder)} is creating a new {nameof(MqttConnection)} and will connect to {this.settings.Server}:{this.settings.Port}.");
        
        var connection = new MqttConnection(this.settings, receiveMessage, loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MqttConnection>());

        await connection.StartAsync();
        logger.LogDebug($"{nameof(MqttConnection)} has been started via {nameof(MqttConnection.StartAsync)}");

        return connection;
    }
}
```

With the above, we now have the interfaces chained correctly, and can register the instances with a inversion of control container clearly separating the concerns of publishing and subscribing:

```
var mqttBusBuilder = new MqttMessageBusBuilder(settings);
var serializers = new [] { MessagePackSerializer };
var idStrategy = new IdentifyUsingTransportHeaders();
mqttBusBuilder
    .Create(serializers, idStrategy, loggerFactory, var out publisher, var out subscriber);

container.RegisterSingleton(publisher);
container.RegisterSingleton(subscriber);
```

With regards to "stopping" the bus, I could create a `BusManager` class to manage a list of created busses and call `StopAsync` on call - alternatively will just perform this transparently by *stopping* in `Dispose()` and let that be a concern of the bus itself as i see other busses do not have `Start` or `Stop` functions so I shouldn't let that be the driver of my interface design.

Comment: `Task.Run(async () => await connection.StartAsync());` returns `Task` which is not awaited in the code. That's bad practice in `async` programming. Also running awaitable method on a separate thread has no sense. You can optimize out thread and keep the same "not awaited" mistake with `_ = connection.StartAsync()` but I suggest to fix it e.g. simple `await connection.StartAsync()`, probably not in this method but outside in a caller's code.

Comment: Valid point - thought was some form of background long running task (which it is not in this case) will get this fixed.